# Configure OpenGeo's Jetty to run php scripts

Tags: php, windows, jetty

I am using OpenGeo package on windows to develop a web mapping application with sdk suite. I would like to create a submit form dialog box with a php script, which saves the data to the database. However, the problem is that it doesn't read 'submit.php' by Jetty server. When I check in firefox, the response shows the whole script only as belown. First, I tested with echo to return true. The created application was debugging on localhost at port 9080 while actual one is localhost:8060 which hosts Opengeo.

I have tried with Php/Java bridge also, however, it is still the same. It works on local host at port 8060/JavaBridge/ and shows the examples. I would really appreciate if you could suggest a way to configure Jetty with php in Opengeo package.

Cheers,
Zar Chi

Comment: There is nothing GIS specific in this question - I think you'll get a better response over here.

Answer (score 0):

We finally solved the problem by working with Ubuntu 12.04LTS and we wanted to share the solution in case is useful for someone else.

1- We installed opengeo following this process: link://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/installation/ubuntu/install.html

2-Then we found this blog: http://www.thomasknierim.com/140/java/

3- And we installed the apache using the fcgi option applying the configuration suggested in these files:

a) link: 2bits.com/articles/apache-fcgid-acceptable-performance-and-better-resource-utilization.html. It was also similar in these other blogs so I went ahead.

b) link: howtoforge.com/using-php5-fpm-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts

c) link: versatilewebsolutions.com/blog/2012/11/installing-apache-2-with-php-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-10.html

4- We followed the instructions here (link: /php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/download.php):

```
Use a graphical packet installer to install PHP. Or download JavaBridge.war, which contains an embedded PHP binary. (I suggest you try again with PHP standalone directly, NOT with JavaBridge.war file)
Download and install Java 6 or above. (/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk)
Download and install the original tomcat servlet engine. (/var/lib/tomcat6)
There must be JavaBridge.jar, php-servlet.jar and php-script.jar files in your /usr/share/tomcat6/lib
Double-check again /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/web.xml
Retart Tomcat server and check it is working now?
```

5- If not, the problem could be related with the permissions of the jar.libraries. There should be accessed by tomcat6:tomcat6. Every deployment called these libraries to automatically create a Java folder which contains Java.inc and JavaProxy.php.